# ec2 inbound traffic between different accounts

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am deploying my web app on EC2. My app consumes a third party REST API. The third party is hosted on US-EAST-1. If I host my app there too does the communication still count as an inbound traffic which there is no need to pay for?

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to the third-party REST API through public DNS (i.e. either a public IP or a public hostname), it will be considered outbound traffic. If the external service sends data back, it will count towards your inbound traffic - this is purely because it's communicating over the public internet (through DNS).

If you want to keep costs down between *your own servers*, move your EC2 instances to a VPC and get them to communicat with eachother through private IP addresses. Private traffic, as far as I'm aware, is free of charge. But you can only have instances of the same availability zone inside one VPC. See [Amazon's pricing model](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) for details:

> **Availability Zone Data Transfer** $0.00 per GB – all data transferred between instances in the same Availability Zone using
>   private IP addresses.
>
> **Regional Data Transfer** $0.01 per GB – all data transferred between instances in different Availability Zones in the same region.